# In Redshift, how do I see where my schema was created?

Tags: schema, amazon-redshift

I am running the following, in a redshift cluster I just created:

```
CREATE SCHEMA myschema;

CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (
  mytable_id INT IDENTITY,
  name varchar(5)
 ) ;

INSERT INTO myschema.mytable (name) VALUES ('BOB'); 

SELECT DISTINCT(tablename) FROM pg_table_def WHERE SCHEMANAME = 'myschema';
```

And I get no results. Isn't the pg_table_def where I am supposed to find the information of my tables?

Comment: I also do not see it if I just run the following either "SELECT DISTINCT(tablename) FROM pg_table_def"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard behavior, and `redshift` only shows

> PG_TABLE_DEF only returns information about tables that are visible to the user. If PG_TABLE_DEF does not return the expected results, verify that the search_path parameter is set correctly to include the relevant schemas.

Refer documentation link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html

Other reason could be search path.
Try setting search path and run it again.

Hope it helps.